Making the substitution $x=e^y$ in the integral $\int_0^1 x^{2n} \ln x/(1+x^2) dx$
$$
\mbox{The integral}\quad
\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{1 + x^{2}}{\rm d}x\quad \mbox{converges to}\quad  r_{n} + {\rm C}s_{n}
$$
when $n$ is a non negative integer.
Where $r_{n},s_{n}$ are rational numbers and ${\rm C}$ is the Catalan Constant. Making $x = {\rm e}^{y}$ would result in
$$
\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{1 + x^{2}}
{\rm d}x =
-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{2ny}\,
\frac{y{\rm e}^{y}}{1 + {\rm e}^{2y}}{\rm d}y
$$
I went to Wolfram Alpha and it seems that this is only true when $n = 0$. If $n > 0$ the right hand side integral will diverge. What I did wrong $?$.

by $\infty$ do you mean $-\infty$?

Separate from your current question, I'm curious what your end goal is and why you wanted to use that substitution?

@SineoftheTime I did: $\int_{-\infty}^0=-\int_0^{\infty}$

@Pinteco $\int_{-\infty}^0=-\int_0^{-\infty}$. You should take $x=\mathrm{e}^{-y}$ instead.

@Gary I see, thank you!

if you want to have $+\infty$ in the bound of integration, you have also to change the sing of the exponential, i.e. you have to make the substitution $y=-u$

@Pinteco Did any of us answer your question?

@Pinteco Did any of us answer your question?

Noticing that $$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2 n} \ln x}{1+x^2} d x=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} d x\right|_{a=2 n}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =\int_0^1 \frac{x^a}{1+x^2} d x \\
& =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^m \int_0^1 x^{a+2 m} d x \\
& =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{a+2 m+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ at $a=2n$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{2 n} \ln x}{1+x^2} d x & =\left.\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{(a+2 m+1)^2}\right|_{a=2 n} \\
& =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^m}{(2(m+n)+1)^2} \\
& =(-1)^n \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2} \\
& =(-1)^n\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2}\right] \\
& =(-1)^nC+(-1)^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)^2}
\\
& =r_n+Cs_n
\end{aligned}
$$
where $r_n= (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2 k+1)^2}\in \mathbb Q$ and $s_n=(-1)^n.$

It should be $a+2m+1$ in place of $a+2n+1$. Also, $m$ is a dummy variable, it cannot appear at the end. The sum in $r_n$ goes up to $n-1$. There are also missing $(-1)^n$ like factors.

To help you more, $$
\sum\limits_{m = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^m }}{{(2(m + n) + 1)^2 }}}  = ( - 1)^n \sum\limits_{k = n}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}}  = ( - 1)^n \left[ {C - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}} } \right].
$$

Gary, thank you for your help. I shall fix it later.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left.\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\ {\ln\pars{x} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\right\vert_{n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\,\geq\ 0}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.\lim_{\nu\ \to\ 2n}\ \partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{1}\ {x^{\nu} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x\right\vert_{\Re\pars{\nu}\ >\ -1}
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{\nu\ \to\ 2n}\ \partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{1}\ {x^{\nu} - x^{\nu\ +\ 2}\ \over 1 - x^{4}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \sr{x^{4}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}
{1 \over 4}\lim_{\nu\ \to\ 2n}\ \partiald{}{\nu}\int_{0}^{1}
{\,x^{\nu/4\ -\ 3/4}\,\,\, -\ x^{\nu/4\ -\ 1/4}\,\, \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 4}\lim_{\nu\ \to\ 2n}\ \partiald{}{\nu}\left(\int_{0}^{1}
{1 -\ x^{\nu/4\ -\ 1/4}\,\, \over 1 - x}\,\dd x\right.
\\[2mm] & \left.\phantom{{1 \over 4}\lim_{\nu\ \to\ 2n}\ \partiald{}{\nu}} -
\int_{0}^{1}
{1 -\ x^{\nu/4\ -\ 3/4}\,\, \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\right)
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over 4}\lim_{\nu\ \to\ 2n}\ \partiald{}{\nu}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{\nu \over 4} + {3 \over 4}} -
\Psi\pars{{\nu \over 4} + {1 \over 4}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{{1 \over 16}\bracks{\Psi\,'\pars{2n + 3 \over 4} -
\Psi\,'\pars{{2n + 1 \over 4}}}}}
\\[5mm] & \sr{{\rm as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim} -\,{1 \over 8n^{2}} + {3 \over 32n^{4}} + \on{O}\pars{1 \over n^{6}} \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\Psi}$ is the $\ds{Digamma\ Function}$.

It seems to me that the OP wants and explicit form in terms of the Catalan constant. Can that be obtained from your result?

@Gary I don’t know right now, but I will try to find that. Thanks.

@FelixMarin, great answer! Glad to see you again.

Using
$$ \frac1{1+x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2k},\int_0^1x^m\ln(x)\rm dx=-\frac1{(m+1)^2} $$
one has
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{1 + x^{2}}{\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2(n+k)}\ln(x){\rm d}x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{0}^{1}(-1)^kx^{2(n+k)}\ln(x){\rm d}x=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2n+2k+1)^2}=-(-1)^n\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}=( - 1)^n \bigg(C - \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}} \bigg). $$

Observe that
\begin{align*}
C &= \int_0^1 {\frac{{\ln x}}{{1 + x^2 }}{\rm d}x}  = \int_0^1 {\ln x\left( {\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {( - 1)^k x^{2k} }  + ( - 1)^n \frac{{x^{2n} }}{{1 + x^2 }}} \right){\rm d}x} 
\\ &  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {( - 1)^k \int_0^1 {x^{2k} \ln x\,{\rm d}x} }  + ( - 1)^n \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^{2n} \ln x}}{{1 + x^2 }}{\rm d}x} 
\\ &\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \mathop  = \limits^{x = {\rm e}^{ - s/(2k + 1)} } \;\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - s} s\,{\rm d}s} }  + ( - 1)^n \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^{2n} \ln x}}{{1 + x^2 }}{\rm d}x} 
\\ & = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}}  + ( - 1)^n \int_0^1 {\frac{{x^{2n} \ln x}}{{1 + x^2 }}{\rm d}x} .
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^1 {\frac{{x^{2n} \ln x}}{{1 + x^2 }}{\rm d}x}  = ( - 1)^n \left( {C - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)^2 }}} } \right).
$$
