Evaluating $\int_0^1\left( \frac{1}{\ln x} + \frac{1}{1-x} \right) dx =\gamma$
Is possible to evaluate
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)} + \frac{1}{1 - x}\right]{\rm d}x = \gamma
\end{align*}
using the fact that
\begin{align*}
\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k = 1}^{n} {1 \over k} - \ln\left(n\right)\right]
\end{align*}
or it depends on other assumptions ?. When
$\left\vert x\right\vert < 1$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}x^{k}
\end{align*}
integrating from $x = 0$ to $x = 1$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1 - x}{\rm d}x =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k + 1} 
\end{align*}
which appears both in the definition of $\gamma$ and and the initial integral. In general, I believe that
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\left[\frac{1}{\ln\left(x\right)} + \frac{1}{1 - x}\right]{\rm d}x =  \gamma
+\ln\left(n + 1\right) -
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}

Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

@MarkViola It seems that this year the OP is struggling to accept answers to their questions.

@Gary This site used to have a much more interesting set of questions.  So many have been answered that the quality of this site, in my opinion, has declined markedly.  I suppose with such a delcine, many of those who post questions now simply don't care about maintaining the integrity of the site.

@MarkViola  I asked for a proof of this idendity and there are 3 different correct answers, which one should I choose when this happens?

@Pinteco You are free to choose any one of them, or none of them at all.  Which one is the simplest to understand?  Which one resonates with you the most?  Which one would you adopt going forward?

@Pinteco There is also an answer waiting for your acceptance here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4916237

We make use of the identity that $\int_0^1 x^t\,dt=\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}$.   Then we have
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \left(\frac1{\log(x)}+\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\,dx&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{(x-1)/\log(x)}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{\int_0^1 x^t\,dt}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\int_0^1 (x^t-1)\,dt}{x-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^t-1}{x-1}\,dt\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1-x^t}{1-x}\,dx\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1  \int_0^1 (x^n-x^{t+n})\,dx\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1 \left(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{t+n+1}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac1{n+1}-\log\left(\frac{n+2}{n+1}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{n}-\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \log(n+1)\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \log(n)\right)\\\\
&=\gamma
\end{align}$$
as was to be shown!

Nice solution! I knew it was related to $\int_0^1 H_t\ dt =\gamma$, but couldn't make the connection and had to rely on asymptotic expansions. @Svyatoslav already has a great solution for the general case; do you have any ideas?

Nice to hear form you :) As far as I can see, your approach allows to evaluate a more general integral:
$$I(a)=\int_0^1\left(\frac{x^a-1}{\ln x}-1\right)\frac{x^n}{x-1}dx$$ At $a=0$ you get the initial integral $I(n)$ of OP (your integral is $I(0)$)

My apology - I meant "at $a=1$". Sorry for the typo.

@Svyatoslav Indeed.  You are correct, as always.  ;-))

(+1): That was clever!

@Mittens Thank you!  Much appreciated.

We can use analytical continuation to evaluate the integral
$$I=\int_0^1 x^n\left( \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1{1-x} \right) dx \overset{x=e^{-t}}{=}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-nt}}{e^t-1}-\frac{e^{-t(n+1)}}t\right)dt$$
Let's consider
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-nt}}{e^t-1}-\frac{e^{-t(n+1)}}t\right)t^\alpha dt,\quad\alpha>0$$
Now we are allowed to handle every integral separately
$$I(\alpha)=I_1(\alpha)+I_2(\alpha)\tag{1}$$
$$I_1(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-nt}}{e^t-1}t^\alpha dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-(n+1)t}\left(1+e^{-t}+e^{-2t}+...\right)t^\alpha dt$$
$$=\Gamma(1+\alpha)\left(\frac1{(n+1)^{1+\alpha}}+\frac1{(n+2)^{1+\alpha}}+...\right)=\Gamma(1+\alpha)\left(\zeta(1+\alpha)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^{1+\alpha}}\right)\tag{1a}$$
$$I_2=-\int_0^\infty e^{-(n+1)t}t^{\alpha-1}dt=-\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{(n+1)^\alpha}\tag{2b}$$
Putting (1a) and (1b) into (1) and leading $\displaystyle\alpha\to 0$
$$I(\alpha)=\Gamma(1+\alpha)\zeta(1+\alpha)-\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\alpha(n+1)^\alpha}-\Gamma(1+\alpha)\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^{1+\alpha}}$$
$$=(1-\gamma\alpha)\zeta(1+\alpha)-\frac1\alpha(1-\gamma\alpha)\big(1-\alpha\ln(n+1)\big)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k+O(\alpha)$$
Using also $\displaystyle \zeta(1+\alpha)=\frac1\alpha+\gamma+O(\alpha),\,\alpha\to 0$
$$I(\alpha\to0)=-\frac1\alpha+\zeta(1+\alpha)+\gamma-\gamma\alpha\zeta(1+\alpha)+\ln(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k+O(\alpha)$$
$$I=I(0)=\gamma+\ln(n+1)-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$
Addendum
To prove that we are allowed to take the limit under the integral sign, i.e.
$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}I(\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-nt}}{e^t-1}-\frac{e^{-t(n+1)}}t\right)t^\alpha dt$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\left(t^\alpha e^{-nt}\frac{t-1+e^{-t}}{(e^t-1)t}\right) dt=I(0)\,\,(n=1,2,...)$$
we can apply the dominated convergence theorem.
The function $\displaystyle f(t)=\frac{t-1+e^{-t}}{(e^t-1)t}$ is continuous and non-negative on $\displaystyle t\in[0;\infty)$ (the function $\,\displaystyle t-1+e^{-t}$ has a positive derivative and $\,=0$ at $t=0$). $\,f(0)=\frac12$ and $f(\infty)=0$; it means that $f(t)$ has a finit maximum value somewhere on the interval. Let's denote it $f_{max}$
It follows that the integrand is dominated by the integrable function $\displaystyle g(t)=f_{max}e^{-nt}, t\in[0;1];\,g(t)=f_{max}e^{-nt}t, t\in[1;\infty)$

How do you know that $\lim_{\alpha \to 0}I(\alpha)=I(0)$?

@Gary, thank you for the relevant point. I added the proof to the post.

@Svyatoslav How are you my friend!  It's been quite a while since we last communicated here.  Please have a look at my posted solution and let me know your thoughts.

Let $0\le A\le 1$,
$$\int_0^A \frac{1}{\log x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\ dx = \operatorname{li}(A)-\log (1-A)$$
where the logarithmic integral $\operatorname{li}(A)$ is
$$\operatorname{li}(A)=\log (1-A)+\gamma-\frac{1-A}{2}+O\left((1-A)^2\right)$$
as $A\to 1$. Hence,
$$\int _0^A \frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\ dx\to \gamma$$
as $A\to 1$.

Edit: General Integral
Call the integral $I_n$ for $n > 1$. Distribute the $x^n$ factor and note that
$$\frac{x^n}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$
so we can rewrite as
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\log x}+\frac{1}{1-x}\ dx-\int _0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ dx.$$
By linearity,  the integral on the right is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\ dx=  \int _0^1 \sum_{k=1}^n x^{k-1}\ dx=\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^1 x^{k-1}\ dx=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$
where the $n$-th Harmonic number appears. For the remaining integral, Mathematica gives
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{\log x} +\frac{1}{1-x}\ dx=\gamma +\log (n+1)$$
as expected, which will prove OP's claim. I assume similar analysis to the special case above - via asymptotics of logarithmic/exponential integrals - will suffice to evaluate the integral.

@Svyatoslav. Do you know how we may show the remaining integral here? Could you perhaps give a hint?

Please have a look at my posted solution.

We can do, for example, the following:
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^n}{\log x} +\frac{1}{1-x}\right) dx\overset{x=e^{-t}}{=}-\int_0^\infty \left(e^{-(n+1)t}-\frac t{e^t-1}\right)\frac{dt}t$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}-(n+1)\int_0^\infty\ln t,e^{-(n+1)t}dt-\int_0^\infty\ln t\left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac t{e^t-1}\right)dt$$
Now we have only to show that the last integral is zero.
